# How to vertically center a view inside vertical linear layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, center

I have a vertical linear layout that wraps another vertical linear layout.

how can i make the inner linear layout to be vertically centered?

as I know vertical linear layout force its children to start positioning from left top.

```
<LL vertical> //outer

  <LL vertical> //inner - is used to group
    <textView> //just a view to be vertically centered
    </textView>
  <LL vertical>

    <anotherView/>

</LL vertical>
```

When i remove the outer linear layout I see the inner one is vertical centered to its parent.

How can i achieve the same vertical centering? The outer linear layout is needed for grouping.

I can wrap the vertical LL with horizontal LL and then the vertical_center of its sons will be effective. but isn't this wasteful?

Comment: Does it have to be a linear layout? You could just use a relative layout and give the attribute android:centerVeritical="true"

Comment: Or use constraintlayout

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/layout1"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1">

   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/inner_layout"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:gravity="center_vertical"
       android:orientation="vertical">

       <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Text 1" />
   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:id="@+id/layout2"
       android:layout_weight="1">

       <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Another View" />
   </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

It can be achieved like in above layout. Put all your views which are above to inner layout in layout1 and all those should come below inner_layout in layout2

Comment: can you please explain?